# How to add a custom variable in a custom SQL call

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am trying to query against an array of strings. The me_topics_users table is an auto-generated table by Rails so to query it, I must use custom SQL.

```
@topics = self.distributions.map(&:me_topic).compact
ActiveRecord::Base.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM `me_topics_users` WHERE (me_topic_id IN (#{@topics.join(', ')}))")
```

But this returns :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `abstract_class?' for Object:Class
from /Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2207:in `class_of_active_record_descendant'
from /Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/ac
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Updated with Substitution but still get the same error**

```
ActiveRecord::Base.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM `me_topics_users` WHERE (me_topic_id IN (?) )", @topics.join("', '")])
```

A simpler version:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(["SELECT * FROM me_topics_users WHERE me_topic_id= ?", '4'])
```

returns:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TypeError: wrong argument type Array (expected String): SELECT * FROM me_topics_users WHERE me_topic_id= ?4
from /Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:212:in `log'
from /Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:320:in `execute'
from (irb):51
from :0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM `me_topics_users` WHERE (me_topic_id IN ('#{@topics.join("', '")}') )")
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. It may work fine now, but just wait until someone hits you with a [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @BrianDonovan how about a little wisdom then! :) I am also trying to avoid doing this...  I'm using ActiveRecord outside of rails, and sanitize_sql is a bit of a tricky loophole

Comment: @RGB What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I can probably help you out. Link me to a new Stackoverflow question though. I'd like to unpack your situation outside of this comment thread.

Answer (score 0):

you can use string replacement techniques as you can with ActiveRecord#find

```
find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM `me_topics_users` WHERE (me_topic_id IN (?))",@topics.join(', ')])
```

Comment: Not really. I've tried this in many ways and it doesn't seem to work.. `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(["SELECT * FROM ?", me_topics_users])`

Comment: Another example of this not working, `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(["SELECT * FROM me_topics_users WHERE me_topic_id= ?", '4'])`

Comment: ok, the find_by_sql works for activerecords only. I think you got it working.. I can see it in your answer